# Flurry - Protect public key

Tags: android, flurry, api-key

In order to send events to Flurry they provide an API Key. Do i have to protect that key in my Android App ?

If yes, what's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would really need to protect an analytics key. I sincerely doubt some hacker wants to inject rogue usage into your analytics.

Beyond that, a couple of ways to protect the key that come to mind are:

1. Construct it from a base 64 string or something at runtime. Not very good protection, but it prevents someone who's just reading the code from getting it.
2. Store it on your server, and pull it at runtime through a webservice or something. That way, its not compiled into the app to begin with, and its harder to retrieve.

None of this makes it impossible to get though, but you shouldn't really need to protect it.

Comment: I have business reasons to protect this key. I can't let anyone get a hold of it and create false calls to my analytics. Thanks for your answer though.